# How can I macro #define a static method call in C++?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, static-methods

I am trying to write software that can behave differently based on whether or not a certain component should be simulated in software or execute on real hardware. However, GCC complains that the Scope resolution operator (::) cannot be used in a macro, so my question is: is it possible to define a macro to a static method call?

My goal is to be able to, using another preprocessor define, choose between using all real components (0), using all simulated components (1), or using a mix of real and simulated components (2). This last case is where I am running into this issue. Under this condition, I want to call a function which I am "protecting" by implementing it as a static method. Here is my approach:

```
#define SIM_CONF 2

#if SIM_CONF == 0
#define IS_HW_SIMULATED(name) false
#define IS_HW_REAL(name) true
#endif

#if SIM_CONF == 1
#define IS_HW_SIMULATED(name) true
#define IS_HW_REAL(name) false
#endif

#if SIM_CONF == 2
#define IS_HW_SIMULATED(name) SimConfig::isSimulated(name)
#define IS_HW_REAL(name) SimConfig::isReal(name)
#endif

class SimConfig
{
public:

    static bool isSimulated(const char* szName);
    static bool isReal(const char* szName);
};
```

**EDIT:** Here's an example of how I use it elsewhere:

```
void PumpComponent::commandRevs(float revs)
{
#if IS_HW_SIMULATED("PumpComponent")
    // do simulation procedure
#else
    // do real hardware procedure
#endif
}
```

When I compile, GNU Make complains:

> ```
> error: token "::" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
> #define IS_HW_SIMULATED(name) SimConfig::isSimulated(name)
> ```

Is there some approach where I can protect/encapsulate the `isSimulated()` and `isReal()` functions, and still be able to refer to them in preprocessor directives?

Comment: Using macros for such things is usually frowned upon in C++ in particular.  There are almost invariably better ways to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve without using macros.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d43f172458803ff). which version do you use?

Comment: ... and how are you invoking the compiler on that file?

Comment: I understand that and definitely would prefer avoiding macros, unfortunately the codebase I am working on already strongly relies on them. I am wondering if there is a way I can work within these bounds without completely refactoring the rest of the software.

Comment: Does the code shown reproduce the error for you — is it an MCVE ([MCVE])?  It works fine for me, even with fairly stringent compilation options, as indeed I'd expect.  Note that you can no longer use `#if IS_HW_SIMULATED("vdu")` when the `SIM_CONF` value is `2`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why does ```#define SIM_CONF 2``` make ```#if IS_HW_SIMULATED("vdu")``` invalid?

Comment: It would be invalid because the scope resolution operator (::) cannot be used in a macro.

Comment: Looks like code is incomplete. To see why this is a problem we need to see how you use `IS_HW_SIMULATED` since in that context macro gains sense. Definition looks fine.

Comment: Using `#if IS_HW_SIMULATED("vdu")` becomes invalid because the C++ preprocessor does textual substitution and does not understand C++ (or C).  It ends up trying to process `SimConfig::isSimulated("vdu")` and `::` is not valid in a C++ preprocessor expression.  In fact, using the configurations `SIM_CONF` of `0` or `1` may not do what you expect (AFAIK) because neither `true` nor `false` is a defined macro in C++ (they're keywords), so they are both translated to 0 by the C++ preprocessor.

Comment: @MarekR I am simply calling ```#if IS_HW_SIMULATED("name") /* do stuff */ #endif``` in a function elsewhere, the compiler reaches that macro and throws an error upon attempting replace it with my static call

Comment: Now we see a problem. This macro can't be used like that!

Comment: @MarekR I added a more verbose example to the post. Could you explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is how you use this macro. You have placed it as preprocessor `#if` argument.

Processor do not understand code and argument of `#if` must be something what processor can handle, so macros and literals.

`SimConfig::isSimulated` is a code which in not defined yet. It will be know during compilation process, so after preprocessing is completed.

One way to fix it is simply use `if` `else`

```
void PumpComponent::commandRevs(float revs)
{
    if IS_HW_SIMULATED("PumpComponent") {
        // do simulation procedure
    } else {
        // do real hardware procedure
    }
}
```

It is not problem for compiler. it will noticed that this is constant and should remove obsolete code.

Other way to fix it is to abandon macros. You can use templates.

Or enclose macro depended stuff in some class and use macros to alter that class functionality (this way this macros will not spread all over your code).

Comment: "You can use templates". More importantly, you can use `constexpr` and then `if constexpr`. Then the compiler **must** the `false` case.

Comment: Switching the class to a template class fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `#if` for this. Just write normal code:

```
void PumpComponent::commandRevs(float revs)
{
    if (IS_HW_SIMULATED("PumpComponent")) {
        // do simulation procedure
    } else {
        // do real hardware procedure
    }
}
```

The compiler will delete one of the branches when `SIM_CONF` is 0 or 1, since the branch condition is a compile-time constant. It will keep the branches when it's 2.

However, I don't see a reason to have the `IS_HW_SIMULATED` and `IS_HW_REAL` macros at all. Looking at the code you posted, it seems you only need one function: `SimConfig::isSimulated()`:

```
bool SimConfig::isSimulated(const char* szName)
{
#if SIM_CONF == 1
    (void)szName; // supress "unused parameter" warning
    return true;
#else
    // Your normal implementation.
#endif
}
```

The rest of your code doesn't need to use any macros then:

```
void PumpComponent::commandRevs(float revs)
{
    if (SimConfig::isSimulated("PumpComponent")) {
        // do simulation procedure
    } else {
        // do real hardware procedure
    }
}
```

`SimConfig::isReal()` doesn't seem to serve any purpose.